# JSON-code doesn't show my picture in my list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have added JSON-code to my list column "Person" which displays the persons name and profile picture. But it doesn't show my profile picture. What do i do wrong?

```
{
 "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "flex-direction": "column",
  "align-items": "flex-start",
  "margin-top": "6px",
  "padding-right": "8px",
  "width": "100%",
  "overflow": "hidden"
    },
 "children": [{
  "forEach": "personIterator in @currentField",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
   "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLight ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary"
  },
  "style": {
   "display": "inline-flex",
   "align-items": "center",
            "height": "28px",
            "overflow": "hidden",
   "border-radius": "12px",
   "padding-right": "8px",
   "margin": "2px"
  },
  "children": [
            {
    "elmType": "img",
    "attributes": {
     "src": "='/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=' + [$personIterator.email]",
     "title": "[$personIterator.title]"
    },
    "style": {
     "width": "28px",
     "height": "28px",
     "display": "block",
     "border-radius": "50%"
    }
   },
   {
                "elmType": "div",
                "txtContent": "[$personIterator.title]",
                "attributes": {
                    "title": "[$personIterator.title]",
                    "class": "nameplate-title"
                },
                "style": {
                    "padding-left": "5px",
                    "white-space": "nowrap",
                    "font-size": "12px"
                }
            }
  ],
  "defaultHoverField": "[$personIterator]"
 }]
}
```

Comment: First try manually running the URL generated in `src` attribute and see if it is referring to correct picture URL.

Comment: I have run the url and it download the placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using above JSON code in my SharePoint tenant and it is working fine for person or group column (with multiple selection allowed).

Also, you don't need to use JSON for showing profile picture along with person name in list view. You can achieve this using out of the box column settings (with new feature in SharePoint).

Follow below steps:

1. Go to SharePoint list & click on small dropdown next to column header.
2. Select **Column settings** and then **Edit**.

[image]

3. Change **Show profile photos** to **Yes**.
4. Click Save

[image]